# What are the possible benefits and disadvantages of reading csv file using DictReader?

Tags: python

What are the pros and cons of reading csv files by mapping data into a dictionary (i.e. using DictReader module) as shown in the code below rather than using reader = csv.reader(csvfile)?

```
import csv
with open("file.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
     print(dict(row))

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `dict` on the dicts the `DictReader` gave you?

Comment: Besides being able to support many variations or "dialects" of the non-standardized format, `DictReader` turns each row into a dictionary which make accessing the fields a little more readable and opens the door to the sorts of processing that is often easier to express as operations on a dictionary.